# Sort Javascript object by value alphabetically

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a JS object as follows:

```
var obj = {"00:11:22:33:44:55" : "AddressB", "66:77:88:99:AA:BB" : "AddressA", "55:44:33:22:11:00" : "AddressC", "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" : "AddressD"};
```

The code as follows sorts it alphabetically via key:

```
sorted = Object.keys(obj)
.sort()
.reduce(function (accSort, keySort) 
{
    accSort[keySort] = obj[keySort];
    return accSort;
}, {});

console.log(sorted);
```

Which produces the output:

> {"00:11:22:33:44:55" : "AddressB", "55:44:33:22:11:00" : "AddressC", "66:77:88:99:AA:BB" : "AddressA", "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" : "AddressD"}

How can I sort the object alphabetically by value so the output is:

> {"66:77:88:99:AA:BB" : "AddressA", "00:11:22:33:44:55" : "AddressB", "55:44:33:22:11:00" : "AddressC", "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" : "AddressD" }

Comment: Although ES6 has specified the order of object properties, you generally shouldn't use objects if order is significant. Use an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to sort by the `keys` by their `values` first, then, use `.reduce` to create the resulting ordered object:

```js
const obj = {
  "00:11:22:33:44:55": "AddressB", 
  "66:77:88:99:AA:BB": "AddressA", 
  "55:44:33:22:11:00": "AddressC", 
  "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF": "AddressD"
};

const sorted = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => obj[a].localeCompare(obj[b]))
  .reduce((acc,key) => { acc[key] = obj[key]; return acc; }, {});

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.entries()` to get a 2-dimensional array of keys and values. Sort that by the values, then create the new object with `reduce()`.

```js
var obj = {"00:11:22:33:44:55" : "AddressB", "66:77:88:99:AA:BB" : "AddressA", "55:44:33:22:11:00" : "AddressC", "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" : "AddressD"};

sorted = Object.entries(obj)
  .sort(([key1, val1], [key2, val2]) => val1.localeCompare(val2))
  .reduce(function(accSort, [key, val]) {
    accSort[key] = val;
    return accSort;
  }, {});

console.log(sorted);
```