# Combine 2 array of objects if matches are found

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have these 2 arrays of objects:

```
const arr1 = [{"id":"pear","qty":2},{"id":"apple","qty":2}];
const arr2 = [{"id":"pear","qty":5},{"id":"lemon","qty":1}];
```

I want to combine them but at the same time summing their values in `qty` when they have the same `id`. This is the expected output:

```
[{"id":"pear","qty":7},{"id":"apple","qty":2},{"id":"lemon","qty":1}];
```

I tried this but it only keeps the first object:

```
const newArray = arr1.map((obj) => {
  const secondArrayObj = arr2.find((obj2) => obj2.id === obj.id);
  if (secondArrayObj) {
    return {...secondArrayObj, ...obj}
  }
  return null;
}).filter((obj) => obj != null);
console.log(newArray);
```

What is the best approach here?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390960/javascript-how-to-merge-two-objects-and-sum-the-values-of-the-same-key

Answer (score 1):

For your code,the reason is that you are using `Array.map()`,it will only covnert `arr1` to another array,and will not merge `arr2`

To solve it,we can do it via `Array.reduce()` and `Array.filter()`

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":"pear","qty":2},{"id":"apple","qty":2}];
const arr2 = [{"id":"pear","qty":5},{"id":"lemon","qty":1}];

let arr3 = [...arr1,...arr2]
arr3 = arr3.reduce((a,v) => {
  let obj = a.find(i => i.id === v.id)
  if(obj){
   obj.qty += v.qty 
   }else{
    a.push(v) 
   }
  return a
},[])
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you. By the way, what are exactly the `...` that precede the vars for? I dont quite get that yet.

Comment: _O(n^2)_... ouch

Comment: @Phil yes,if the data number is very large,we need to use a map variable to store it,such as the answer your posted

Comment: @CainNuke It deserialize two arrays and combine them into one array

Comment: Doesn't matter how big it is, it's still _O(n^2)_

Comment: so its like using JSON.unserialize()?

Comment: @CainNuke no,not the same

Comment: @CainNuke see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to skin the cat. Here is one that uses an intermediate `sums` object, which performs well with large arrays:

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":"pear","qty":2},{"id":"apple","qty":2}];
const arr2 = [{"id":"pear","qty":5},{"id":"lemon","qty":1}];

let sums = {};
arr1.concat(arr2).forEach(obj => {
  if(!sums[obj.id]) {
    sums[obj.id] = 0;
  }
  sums[obj.id] += obj.qty;
});
let arr3 = Object.keys(sums).map(id => { return {id: id, qty: sums[id]}; });
console.log(arr3);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "pear",
    "qty": 7
  },
  {
    "id": "apple",
    "qty": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "lemon",
    "qty": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [*Combine*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) both arrays
2. [*Reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them to a map keyed by `id` and value being the sum of `qty`
3. Turn that object back into an array using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
4. [*Map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that back to an array of objects

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":"pear","qty":2},{"id":"apple","qty":2}];
const arr2 = [{"id":"pear","qty":5},{"id":"lemon","qty":1}];

const newArray = [
  ...arr1
    .concat(arr2)
    .reduce(
      (map, { id, qty }) => map.set(id, qty + (map.get(id) ?? 0)),
      new Map()
    ),
].map(([id, qty]) => ({ id, qty }));

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Isn't spreading `map` on every iteration of the reduce also going to result in O(n^2), where n is the number of unique ids?

Comment: its nice because its simple and works but Im getting syntax errors: Expected and identifier and instead saw '?'

Comment: @CainNuke what browser / Node version are you using? The [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) is well supported on modern platforms

Comment: @danh interesting observation. I need to do a little research on the matter but using a `Map` instead should negate that

Comment: im on firefox latest version.

Comment: @CainNuke me too and it works just fine when I hit _"Run code snippet"_.

Comment: it does work but it gives me syntax errors. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/csw8f0zj/

Comment: @CainNuke I don't see any errors reported. If you're talking about the red lines in the editor, that's just JSFiddle's default linter / ES language level

Comment: Was closing old tabs, and I noticed your edit. I think the significant change is in mutating rather than copying the reduce accumulator each iteration. Doing this with a Map vs a generic object seems to me less important.

Comment: @danh yep, I just used Map because it's got a nice interface and `set()` returns the Map